# Meteor + IronRouter -- how can I redirect the user after logging in without blocking access to my landing page?

Tags: redirect, meteor, authentication, iron-router, meteor-accounts

In my app, I have the `loginButtons` on the landing page.
I would like users to be automatically redirected to the `/home` route after a successful login.

This code seems to accomplish that:

```
// Redirect to /home after logging in
Accounts.onLogin(function() {
  Router.go("/home");
});

// Make sure the user is logged in when accessing other routes
Router.onBeforeAction((function() {
  if (!Meteor.userId() && !Meteor.loggingIn()) {
    Router.go("/");
  }
  this.next();
}), {
  except: ["/"]
});
```

However, when a logged-in user then tries to access the landing page again, they get redirected to the `/home` route. This effectively blocks their access to the landing page.

How can I redirect users to `/home` after logging in without preventing them from accessing the landing page afterwards?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix it using the [`u2622:persistent-session`](https://atmospherejs.com/u2622/persistent-session) package:

```
// Redirect to /home after logging in
Accounts.onLogin(function() {
  if (!Session.get("loginRedirected")){
      Router.go("/home");
      Session.setAuth("loginRedirected", true);
  }
});
```

The `Session.setAuth` method it adds creates session variables in `localstorage` so that they persist across page refreshes. It even automatically clears them when the user logs out.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in my app. I basically did the following on my *home* page:

```
<template name="home">
{{#if currentUser}}
  {{> loggedInHome }}
{{else}}
  {{> landing }}
{{/if}}
</template>
```

Then I created a *route* to `/landing` and provided navigation to it. The result is:

1. Not-logged in user arrives at `/`
2. User sees landing page content
3. User logs in or registers
4. User is brought back to `/`
5. `/` now shows main app
6. Landing page is available in nav to logged user

It may not be the most elegant solution but it gets the job done.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I fixed it using session variables.